# Element of List of list to List

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of list(tuple of tuple?) of number

`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

I want to transform in:

`(123,456,789)`

I did with this code, can you suggest to me a better way to do it?

```
listacomb = []
for list in permdue:
    for number in list:
        numerix += "".join(str(number))
    listacomb.append(numerix)
    numerix=""
return listacomb
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a list comprehension:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
output = tuple([int("".join(map(str, inner_list))) for inner_list in data])
print(output)
```

Output:

```
(123, 456, 789)
```

**References:**

- [Python documentation on List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a math approach to doing this.  We can iterate each sublist backwards and build out the desired number.

```
permdue = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
listacomb = []

for list in permdue:
    list = reversed(list)
    m = 1
    numerix = 0
    for number in list:
        numerix += number * m
        m = m * 10
    listacomb.append(numerix)

print(listacomb)  # [123, 456, 789]
```

This approach avoids the performance penalizing string solution.  It works, for example, by taking `[1, 2, 3]` and computing `3 + 20 + 100`, to obtain 123.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without reversal like this:

```
permdue = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
listacomb = []

for p in permdue:
    n = 0
    for p_ in p:
        n = n * 10 + p_
    listacomb.append(n)
print(listacomb)
```

**Output:**

```
[123, 456, 789]
```